# error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. 65 map(value => this._filter(value))

Tags: typescript, angular11

I have angular 11 installed
typescript 4.1.5

Below code is used for autocomplete for input type text

```
 myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
 options: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e'];
 filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit() {  

    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
}



  private _filter(val: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

I am using above function which is on mat material official website but getting

- error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

65         map(value => this._filter(value))

Comment: `this._filter` returns `unknown`. Please show us `this._filter`.

Comment: Thank you for replying, edited question with _filter please find question above again Thank you

Comment: how is `this.options` declared?

Comment: @apokryfos Thank for your time i have updated question please find updated question above